# cordova how to divide notification callback in foreground and background?

Tags: cordova, push-notification

cordova version is 6.5.0 and I'm using phonegap-plugin-push 1.9.4 "PushPlugin".

I just want to seperate notification callback depends on app's status(foreground and background).

for example,
when app is in foreground, callback function will execute some operation without page change.
On the other hands, when background, I want callback to execute page move.

How can I set notification options?

```
...
push.on('notification', function(data) {
  if(foreground) {
    $(div).append("<a></a>");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "xxx.html";
  }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You have ***foreground*** boolean on notification payload (in ***additionalData*** property of push payload, as reported on [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/android/com/adobe/phonegap/push/PushPlugin.java) class of your plugin).

Use something like this:

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
  if(data.additionalData.foreground) {
    $(div).append("<a></a>");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "xxx.html";
  }
}
```